# 'ProductFlavor.resConfigs' has a value 'auto' which is obsolete and has not been replaced

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.1

How to fix the warning below? Are there any alternatives to 'auto'?

> Warning:DSL element 'ProductFlavor.resConfigs' has a value 'auto' which is obsolete and has not been replaced. It will be removed at the end of 2018

```
android {
    ...
    flavorDimensions "device", "paid", "market"
    productFlavors {
        phone {
            // Phone config version for the application
            resConfigs ("auto")
            dimension "device"
            matchingFallbacks = ['mobile']
        }
        ...     
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the error after updating to Android Studio 3.1:

[image]

Based on the official advise [here](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor:resConfigs(java.lang.String[])) the best thing to do is removing the tag entirely if you support all the languages or supply an array with the language's code your app supports like:

```
resConfigs "en", "de", "it", "fr" // etc. etc.
```

**More info:**

This is one of the resources optimization proposed by the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#unused-alt-resources) so i decided to test this flag with those `FirebaseUI` dependencies in a sample project

```
implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:$firebase_ui_version"
implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:$firebase_ui_version"
implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:$firebase_ui_version"
```

creating the debug APK with both the options and those are the results:

> - Using `resConfigs "auto"` the debug APK was: 3,793 KB
> - Using `resConfigs "en"` (so 1 language only) the debug APK was: 3,294 KB

This means that with all the string resources for all the languages of those dependencies *I got only ~500KB of size increase*. That's something you could reason about, you definitely should make a test with the dependencies you use and see if the size increase is negligible or not and consequently decide to provide the list of supported languages or remove the `resConfigs` option.

PS: If you are using Android `FirebaseUI` this was one of the suggested optimizations, I've created an issue [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1217) about the thing and this has been solved immediately by the awesome guy called `SUPERCILEX`

Answer (score 1):

`auto` is no longer supported because it created a number of issues with multi-module projects. Instead, you should specify the locale that your app supports. Android plugin 3.1.0 and higher ignore the `auto` argument, and Gradle packages all string resources your app and its dependencies provide.

*com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha08* **BaseFlavor.java**

```
 * <p><b>Note:</b> <code>auto</code> is no longer supported because it created a number of
 * issues with multi-module projects. Instead, you should specify the locale that your app
 * supports, as shown in the sample above. Android plugin 3.1.0 and higher ignore the <code>auto
 * </code> argument, and Gradle packages all string resources your app and its dependencies
 * provide.
```

Comment: You mention that "it created a number of issues with multi-module projects". I know the official docs say this, but do you know where I can find more information about specifically what the issues were? For instance I have been trying to find the commit that made `auto` a noop but have been unable to find it (are the sources for the 3.1.0 plugin even published yet?).

Comment: @Aaron  Sorry, I don't know where you can find more information about specifically what the issues were. Sources for the 3.1.0 plugin - `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0/gradle-3.1.0.pom`

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the pom only links you to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base, where I am unable to find sources past 3.0.0.

Comment: @Aaron https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0/gradle-3.1.0-sources.jar https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/3.1.0/gradle-core-3.1.0-sources.jar etc.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I overlooked the source jars. Also Google has now published the git history for 3.1.2 and I was able to find the commit I was looking for (though it still doesn't really explain the issue): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/6b7799c36f1ba5194f73f5c14a7b0365a8428714%5E%21/